# Add a new APT mirror from command-line

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, mirrors

I need to add a new APT mirror via command-line (I have to add it from a Bash Script).

You can found the Bash Script I'm working on here:

[apt-rollback](https://gitlab.com/fabio.dellaria/apt-rollback)

A little Demo here:
[image]

It's a script able to Undo the last APT command.

The Script have to works on every Ubuntu version from the 18.04.

The mirror I need to add is:

[FOSS Oman Ubuntu Mirror - -HTTP](http://mirror.squ.edu.om/ubuntuarchive/)

or

[FOSS Oman Ubuntu Mirror - -HTTPS](https://mirror.squ.edu.om/ubuntuarchive/)

Comment: "I have to add it from a Bash Script" - Why? Is this some sort of homework?

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release, I had a look and not all releases are supported.

Comment: Just added the requested info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches I found this:

[what is the function of /etc/apt/sources.list.d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020917/what-is-the-function-of-etc-apt-sources-list-d)

A little extract:

> The function of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory is as follows:
>
> Using the directory you can easily add new repositories without the
>   need to edit the central `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. I.e. you can just
>   put a file with a unique name and the same format as
>   `/etc/apt/sources.list` into this folder and it is used by apt.
>
> In order to remove this source again you can just remove that specific
>   file without the need for handling side effects, parsing or mangling
>   with `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

I think to can use this method to add my mirror. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumptions as the the commenters already noticed. Have a look at the MAN-pages for apt-mirror management. FOr instance https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html and  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/apt-mirror.1.html

Make sure your release/version is properly supported, otherwise you will break your system (not able to update/upgrade).